# Python: How to use values from divmod in a subsequent subtraction

Tags: python, typeerror, divmod

how do I include the result of a divmod division into a simple subtraction without facing: 
*TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'tuple'?*

Here my code (written in Python):

```
def discount(price, quantity): 
if (price > 100): 
    discounted_price = price*0.9
else: 
    discounted_price = price

if (quantity > 10): 
    deducted_quantity = divmod(quantity, 5)
    discounted_quantity = quantity - deducted_quantity
else: 
    discounted_quantity = quantity

#Compute which discount yields a better outcome   
if (discounted_price*quantity < price*discounted_quantity):
    return(discounted_price*quantity)
else:
    return(price*discounted_quantity)
```

Any help is highly appreciated since I am a beginner and I could not find a fitting solution yet.

Just for your information the underlying task: 
*Write a function discount() that takes (positional) arguments price and quantity and implements a discount scheme for a customer order as follows. If the price is over 100 Dollars, we grant 10% relative discount. If a customers orders more than 10 items, one in every five items is for free. The function should then return the overall cost. Further, only one of the two discount types is granted, whichever is better for the customer.*

[image: Error in full length]

Comment: `divmod` returns the quotient and remainder from the division as a tuple, as the documentation says. Do you need both values?

Comment: `divmod` beasically returns `a // b, a % b`, so just choose the one you need.

Comment: Yes I need both values. How do include these values into my computations?

Comment: `quantity` is a single number; what is `17 - (3, 2)` supposed to produce? Why are you using `divmod` in the first place; what does it mean to divide `quantity` by 5 in this case?

Comment: I know; however what I didnt know was how to get the individual values from the divmod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`divmod` returns a tuple `(d, m)` where `d` is the integer result of the division (`x // y`) and `m` is the remainder (`x % y`), use indexing to get whatever it is you want of the two (`div` or `mod`):

```
deducted_quantity = divmod(quantity, 5)[0]
# or:
# deducted_quantity = divmod(quantity, 5)[1]
```

Or if you need both, use a variable for each value using unpacking:

```
the_div, the_mod = divmod(quantity, 5)
```